# Java: Variable size array of int

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm trying out arraylists and I need to make a variable sized array of integers.
I don't know if I'm implementing it right.
How do I go about doing this? Can someone help me out with the syntax?

```
    Integer[] ints = new Integer[x];
    static List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I want to be able to do things like ints.add(0);
etc.

EDIT: Code:

```
  Integer[] ints = new Integer[x]; 
  static List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
  ints.clear(); 
  for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 < 50; counter2++) { 
      if (list[counter2].userActive == true) { 
        if (list[counter2].getLastName().equals(lastName) || (lastName=="")) { 
           if ((list[counter2].getFirstName().equals(firstName))||(firstName=="")
                && (list[counter2].userActive == true)) 
                ints.add(counter2);
```

Comment: We need to see the code to help you with the syntax.

Comment: Here's what I have.

Integer[] ints = new Integer[x];
static List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.clear();
  for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 < 50; counter2++) {
   if (list[counter2].userActive == true) {
    if (list[counter2].getLastName().equals(lastName) || (lastName=="")) {
     if ((list[counter2].getFirstName().equals(firstName))||(firstName=="") && (list[counter2].userActive == true)) ints.add(counter2);

Comment: You don't have to be sorry. The code should always go either in the question or the answer not the comment. Can you add your code in the question?

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Java api does not have a variable-size array of primitives (other than reference types). There are third-party libraries that do provide this functionality ([GNU trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) is widely used; see [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-collections-%E2%80%93-are-there) for a list good-quality libraries), or you can build your own.

If you don't mind the overhead of boxing/unboxing, you can use an `ArrayList<Integer>`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**EDIT** Looking at the code you posted, the only thing wrong I see is that you are declaring `ints` as both an `Integer[]` and as a `static List<Integer>`. You can't declare the same variable twice. Get rid of the `Integer[]` declaration and the rest of your code looks like it should behave properly (at least the part about adding integer values to a variable-size list; I don't know anything about your logic).